# Custom Adapter for ListView causing Error

Tags: android, android-listview, android-arrayadapter

I am getting this error:

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: 
    Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'
```

This is HomeScreen.java:

```
public class HomeScreen extends ListActivity {

    String TAG = AppConstants.TAG;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.home);

        CBasicInfo basicinfo_data[] = new CBasicInfo[]
                {
                    new CBasicInfo("Projet A", 1, new Date()),
                    new CBasicInfo("Projet A", 2, new Date()),
                    new CBasicInfo("Projet A", 3, new Date()),
                    new CBasicInfo("Projet A", 4, new Date()),
                    new CBasicInfo("Projet A", 5, new Date())
                };

        BasicInfoAdapter adapter = new BasicInfoAdapter(this, R.layout.home_screen_list_item, basicinfo_data);
        ListView list_view = (ListView)findViewById(R.id.lvSavedProjects);
        list_view.setAdapter(adapter);
    }
}
```

And here my adapter BasicInfoAdapter.java:

```
public class BasicInfoAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<CBasicInfo>{

    Context context; 
    int layoutResourceId;    
    CBasicInfo data[] = null;

    public BasicInfoAdapter(Context context, int layoutResourceId, CBasicInfo[] data) {
        super(context, layoutResourceId, data);
        this.layoutResourceId = layoutResourceId;
        this.context = context;
        this.data = data;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        View row = convertView;
        BasicInfoHolder holder = null;

        if(row == null)
        {
            LayoutInflater inflater = ((Activity)context).getLayoutInflater();
            row = inflater.inflate(layoutResourceId, parent, false);

            holder = new BasicInfoHolder();
            holder.txtName = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHomeScreenProjectName);
            holder.txtPid = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHomeScreenPid);
            holder.txtDDate = (TextView)row.findViewById(R.id.tvHomeScreenDownloadDate);

            row.setTag(holder);
        }
        else
        {
            holder = (BasicInfoHolder)row.getTag();
        }

        CBasicInfo bi = data[position];
        holder.txtName.setText(bi.getName());
        holder.txtPid.setText(bi.getId());
        holder.txtDDate.setText(bi.getExportDate().toString());

        return row;
    }

    static class BasicInfoHolder
    {
        TextView txtName;
        TextView txtPid;
        TextView txtDDate;
    }
}
```

My home.xml is:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >
    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_saved_projects"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/lvSavedProjects"
        android:name="android.app.ListFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dip"
        android:layout_weight="0.86" />
    <Button
        android:id="@+id/bDownloadMoreProjects"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="@string/lbl_download_more_projects" />
</LinearLayout>
```

What the heck am I doing wrong here?

Thx

EDIT:

The stack trace shows:

```
FATAL EXCEPTION: main
android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1
    at android.content.res.Resources.getText(Resources.java:247)
    at android.widget.TextView.setText(TextView.java:3473)
    at com.snip.tnc.SnipForAndroid.BasicInfoAdapter.getView(BasicInfoAdapter.java:48)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2033)
    at android.widget.ListView.makeAndAddView(ListView.java:1772)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillDown(ListView.java:672)
    at android.widget.ListView.fillFromTop(ListView.java:732)
    at android.widget.ListView.layoutChildren(ListView.java:1625)
    at android.widget.AbsListView.onLayout(AbsListView.java:1863)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1628)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1486)
    at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1399)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:431)
    at android.view.View.layout(View.java:11278)
    at android.view.ViewGroup.layout(ViewGroup.java:4224)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1489)
    at android.view.ViewRootImpl.handleMessage(ViewRootImpl.java:2442)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4424)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:784)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:551)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is quite clear:

> Your content must have a ListView whose id attribute is 'android.R.id.list'

so it seems you don't have one at `R.layout.home`. By the way, your problem has nothing to do with `Adapter`s but with `ListActivity`.

The `ListView` in your layout should have this as its `id` attribute:

```
android:id="@android:id/list`
```

I'm not sure what your `android:name` attribute is doing there.

Comment: When I change it to that, I get this error: `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1`

Comment: @Eric: Where exactly do you get that?

Comment: I've added the stack trace above.

Comment: @Eric: That's caused by one of your `setText` method calls, probably the one with `getId()` as an argument. If you want a string with the value of such id, you should do something in the lines of `setText(Integer.toString(bi.getId()));`

Comment: This did it! `setText(Integer.toString(bi.getId()));` Thanks for your help. :)

Answer (score 1):

As K-Ballo points out, the layout for a `ListActivity` must have a `ListView` with id `android.R.id.list`. The first part (`android.R`) translates to `@android:` and the second to `id/list` so...

Set the id of you `ListView` to be `@android:id/list`. and it will automatically be used.

You then should delete the line where you use `findViewById(...)` (not necessary for a `ListActivity`). Then you just use...

```
setListAdapter(adapter);
```

You don't need to find the `ListView` to set the `Adapter` as the above method that `ListActivity` exposes does it automatically.

If you do need the `ListView` for other purposes, however, use...

```
getListView();
```

Comment: Yep, did all that and still get `android.content.res.Resources$NotFoundException: String resource ID #0x1`. I've added a stack trace above. Maybe that will help figure it out?